# @Html.ValidationMessageFor always False when using parent model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have searched for an answer to this issue to my wits end. If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

Overview:

I added a parent model so that I can reference multiple models in a single view. In doing so, the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` now always returns false because the URL being generated now reads:

```
/Customer/isFieldValidJson?CUSTOMER.field=selectedValue
```

Before I added the parent model the URL was (which worked):

```
/Customer/isFieldValidJson?field=selectedValue
```

Here is how everything is set up:

Parent Model:

```
namespace WebProject
{
    public class CustomerClassOfTrade
    {
        public CUSTOMERS CUSTOMERS { get; set; }

        public CLASSOFTRADE CLASSOFTRADE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CUSTOMERS Model:

```
namespace WebProject
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaData))]
    public partial class CUSTOMERS
    {
    }

    public class CustomerMetaData
    {
        [Display(Name = "Field:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Must be <= 50 characters")]
        [Remote("isFieldValidJson", "Customer", ErrorMessage = "Field not valid")]
        public string Field { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CLASSOFTRADE Model:

```
namespace WebProject
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(ClassOfTradeLevels))]
    public partial class CLASSOFTRADE
    {
    }

    public class ClassOfTradeLevels
    {
        [Display(Name = "Class of Trade L1:")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Must be <= 50 characters")]
        public string ClassOfTradeL1 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Class of Trade L2:")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Must be <= 50 characters")]
        public string ClassOfTradeL2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Customer Controller:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Read/Write", PageType = "Customer")]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new CustomerClassOfTrade();
    var customer = new CUSTOMERS();
    var classoftrade = new CLASSOFTRADE();

    ViewBag.FieldArray = db.FIELDS.ToList();

    model.CUSTOMERS = customer;
    model.CLASSOFTRADE = classoftrade;

    return View(model);
}

public JsonResult isFieldValidJson(string field)
{
    return Json(isFieldValid(field), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public bool isFieldValid(string field)
{
    return db.FIELDS.Any(ss => ss.Field == field);
}
```

Create View:

```
@model WebProject.CustomerClassOfTrade

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Customer";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CUSTOMERS.Field) 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CUSTOMERS.Field, new SelectList(ViewBag.FieldArray, "Field", "Field"), "Select")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CUSTOMERS.Field)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Please let me know if there is any more information needed. Thank you!

Comment: it wouldn't be work because customers class everytime will update when any modification will happened in db so validation will be remove.so you have put access validation through parent model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your remote validation action to this:

```
public JsonResult isFieldValidJson([Bind(Prefix = "CUSTOMERS")] string field)
{
    return Json(isFieldValid(field), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I added the binding but it did not change the request URL so the response is still false and the error message is still triggered. It still shows: /Customer/isFieldValidJson?CUSTOMERS.Field=selectedValue . Thank you for your response.

Comment: That's not supposed to change the request. It just tells the MVC model binder that it should use "CUSTOMERS" as a prefix when trying to bind the model. Add a `FormCollection values` parameter to your action to see what's posted to your validation action, like this: `public JsonResult isFieldValidJson([Bind(Prefix = "CUSTOMERS")] string field, FormCollection values)`.

Comment: By the way, why is your model's name "CUSTOMERS"? First of all, follow the standard naming conventions; use Customer instead of CUSTOMER. Also, the Customer class represents one customer, so it should not be plural.

Comment: @ataravati: likely a case of using an ORM tool or proxy connecting to a non-canonical system.

Comment: @ataravati I agree, the naming convention above is less than ideal. I inherited this application and as this is the first change I have needed to make I have not yet cleaned everything up. Thank you for the suggestion. I will try adding FormCollection to see what is posted. I have debugged through the adapters.add method in the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file and the prefix is set correctly to "CUSTOMERS" without the binding in the controller.

Comment: @IanC., I don't know if you understood what `[Bind(Prefix = "CUSTOMERS")]` does. That parameter attribute tells the model binder that the model coming from the view is prefixed with "CUSTOMERS", so the model binder will know that it needs to bind "CUSTOMERS.field" to the model ("field"). This should work, unless you're doing something wrong.